# OpenGL, GLFW и swapBuffers

Tags: linux, windows, opengl

Есть код такого вида:

`GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(/*параметры*/);
glfwSwapBuffers(window);`

Так вот, мне интересно, что же на самом деле front и back буферы окна, и что с точки зрения операционной системы происходит при вызове `glfwSwapBuffers()`.

Как я понимаю - ОС, например linux, использует OpenGL для отрисовки всех своих окошек и элементов UI, и получается, что вывод моего приложения в какое-либо окно - по сути отрисовка FrameBuffer текстуркой в прямоугольник созданного окна. Так? Есть ли какие-то ресурсы, где я смогу узнать, как же это работает на уровне системы?

---

И да, я знаю, для чего нужна двойная буферизация, мне интересно именно то, как происходит вывод буфера в окошечко системы, и что в этом процессе управляется системой, а что - видеокартой

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем нужна двойная буферизация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434031/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Ни разу не дубликат. Перечитайте вопрос, он про управление окнами с OpenGL на уровне ОС.

Comment: зачем вам это знать ? собираетесь подобные библиотеки писать ?

Comment: Библиотеки такого рода писать не собираюсь, но хочу работать с железом и драйверами, поэтому и начинаю с более-менее доступного вопроса

Comment: Пример создания 3D окна с 0 - https://youtu.be/iH1xpfOBN6M (цикл видео)

Answer (score 1):

`glfw` это библиотека для работы с окнами в кросс платформенной манере, предоставляющая программисту единый `API` и он не зависит от `openGL` напрямую, это просто обёртка, потому что всю работу связанную с выводом графической информации делает ОС общаясь с видеокартой посредством драйверов, а то как они там общаются - это надо спрашивать у разработчиков ОС или копайтесь в соотвествующих исходниках ОС (уверен вы ещё не пробовали).

Comment: Да, я прекрасно понимаю, какую функциональность дает glfw. Мне как раз интересно, каким образом это происходит между системой и видеокартой. Попробую разобраться на linux, благо исходники открыты